# Error while trying to dual boot Windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: dual-boot, systemd, acpi, recovery-mode

This is what I see after the installation process while trying to restart.

[image]

If I restart manually, I can't access Ubuntu normally. I can only access it from recovery. Normal way gets stuck between log in screen and opening (purple screen) without access to mouse or keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Try rebooting into your live cd, dvd, or usb and reinstall Ubuntu like this:

1. Upon booting, click “Install Ubuntu”
2. Go through the installation process until you get to where it asks you what type of installation type you would like to use. Select “Something Else” and find the one that says that it has Ubuntu 18.04 on it.
3. Select the Ubuntu 18.04 partition, and click the Change button. This will open a window. Make sure to set “Use as” to ext4 journaling file system. Set mount point as /. Click ok.
4. Make sure that the “Device for bootloader installation is set to your hard drive. Click “Install Now”. Continue the rest of the installation as normal.
5. Once the installation is done, reboot the system. This should bring up the Grub Menu. It should look something like this. [GNU Grub Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F2R11.jpg) Make sure that both Ubuntu and Windows 10 are displayed. If they aren’t, we’ve got other problems. Boot into Ubuntu or Windows regularly.

NOTE: If this does not work, your ISO is most likely damaged or corrupted. Re-download the ISO from www.ubuntu.com and re-write it to the USB drive. Then re-do the process.

Comment: I've done what u said , but at the end of the installation i got that https://ibb.co/8z4GtX0
https://ibb.co/Xy02j6X
https://ibb.co/fNZC53m
https://ibb.co/XjrHSQc
https://ibb.co/0rJwHzR
https://ibb.co/NsNqhqs
https://ibb.co/NsNqhqs

Comment: @VladStefan I think your ISO might be corrupted. Try re-downloading the Ubuntu ISO from www.ubuntu.com and re-write it to the USB Drive. Boot into it and do the same exact thing I told you to do in the answer.

Comment: I'll try , tho that actual iso is from official site , idk how got corrupted

Comment: It was probably corrupted during either the download process or the writing process.

Comment: Did it , no change , tryed to boot the usb from my roommate laptop too . Also i installed on his computer and he gets a similar problem but mot the same...

Comment: More ideas ?....

Comment: Try with a different USB?

Comment: With a different usb gets freez in deferent points of instalation

Comment: I dont know what to tell u man, sounds like it could be a multitude of problems.

Comment: That's not a good hearing...